# Converting JSONArray String to array

Tags: java, json, string

I have this JSON data

```
{"mydata":{"numbers":[12,23,34]}}
```

By taking JSONObject I get following object:

```
JSONObject obj = mydataObj.getJSONObject("mydata");
```

So obj is this:

```
{"numbers":[12,23,34]}
```

I need to use the numbers elements. So I will make a for-loop to use elements.

```
String numbers = myObject.getString("numbers");
```

This gives a string like this:

```
["12","23","34"]
```

How can I convert this to an array or arraylist?
So I will have an array having values of 12, 23 and 34.

Edit: After getting the Array, ArrayList of JSONArray, I will compare "numbers1_Array" and "numbers2_Array". Then I will find the elements that exists in first array but doesn't exists in second array. So selecting data structure type related to which compare operation is easier.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`getJSONArray()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `getString()`, and then simply iterate over the [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and build your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Is it possible to compare to JSONArrays and find the differences between them ?

Comment: I haven't tried it.  If you're just interested in finding out whether they're identical or not, you might get away with comparing their String representations, otherwise you might need to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("numbers");
   List list<Long> = new ArrayList<Long>(); 

    for(int i=0; i < jArray .length(); i++)
        list.add(new Long((String)jArray .get(i)));
```

Comment: What is second array.You have one?

Comment: For brevity I removed it. Seconds array's structure is the same as first one. Only values are different.

Answer (score 0):

after getting the object in JSONObject
what you have is

```
JSONObject obj ===>>> {"numbers":[12,23,34]}
```

now this object is an array
so you cant just access an array by passing name only
you have to do something like this

```
JSONArray numbers = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("numbers");
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
                    // this iterator.next() is your element from the JSON array
                    //you can store like 
                    // int val = iterator.next()
                    // better you store this in an array 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Others solutions are fine, you can also do with your string like this

```
numbers=numbers.substring(1,s.length()-1).replaceAll("\"","");
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<String>();
sample.addAll(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way using Guava. https://github.com/google/guava

```
    String numbers = myObject.getString("numbers");
    List list = new ArrayList();
    JSONArray numbersJsonArray = new JSONArray(numbers);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersJsonArray.length(); i ++) {
        list.add(numbersJsonArray.getInt(i));
    }// after this loop if what you need is the array list you have it all in the list


    int[] array = Ints.toArray(list); // if you need array of ints
```