# retrieve JSON data in JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp, getjson

I am getting a successful response from my jQuery GET request to my servlet. I have set the response in JSON format, but I am not able to parse that data. My JSON response is coming back in this format.

`{"A":[[a1,a2],[b1,b2]]}`

This is in the form of `Map<List<List<String>>>`.

If you see in the response the Map is A and than a upper List which contains two inner list `[a1,a2]` and `[b1,b2]`.

Can someone please let me know how I can retrieve the inner list data in JSP. I could see this response in alert.

Comment: does [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18959730/1283215) help

Comment: This Link Helps alot..Thank You.. I have one more question ,Please help. I am sending response of JSOn from my servlet like this out.print(jsonobject1) but i have another object which is jsonobject2. So my question is how i can send both the object together ....i tried this out.print(jsonobject1+jsonobject2) but it throws error ? Thanks again....

Comment: use a JSON object array

Comment: i believe JSONObject Array can not be used inside javascript ? i have to parse the JSOn object i recieved , i wanted to know how can i parse this form of data.....

Comment: give it a google man , how to pass JSON object in javascript array

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access [a1,a2] use :

```
data[0][0][0]
```

and for [b1,b2] use :

```
data[0][0][1]
```

Comment: Thanks..what if i want to retrieve only a1 ?