# Json. converting many objects from one json

Tags: java, json

if i have simple json with

```
{   
    "age":29,
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "name":"mkyong"
}
```

i use this code

```
public class JacksonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {

        // read from file, convert it to user class
        User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);

        // display to console
        System.out.println(user);

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

and get, one object. but what if i have

```
{
    "age":29,
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "name":"alice"
}
{
    "age":18,
    "messages":["msg 4","msg 5","msg 6"],
    "name":"bob"
}
```

how can i get all objects from one json file and add their to list? sorry for my bad english

Comment: The thing you're trying to parse is not a valid JSON. You should wrap it in array or something, like this: `[{"age":29, ... },{"age":18, ... }]`. On how to parse an array, you can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18959730/1283215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JSON array of `User`s you can de-serialize:

- As a Collection of `User`:

  `om.readValue("myFile", new TypeReference<Collection<User>>() {});`
- As an `array` of `User`

  `om.readValue("myFile", User[].class);`

You're probably going to need your JSON file to be fixed, as pointed out by [SimY4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1439771/simy4).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Class<?> clz = Class.forName(type);
JavaType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clz);
List <T> record = mapper.readValue(json, listType);
```